# Xcode 4 + SVN. Adding branches question

Tags: ios, xcode, svn, branch

[This](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/ToolsLanguages/Conceptual/Xcode4UserGuide/SCM/SCM.html) document tells:

> In the repositories organizer, select the appropriate Branches
>   directory in the navigator pane and click the Add Branch button

Where is that button? In Organizer I see only disabled "Switch branch" button...

Answer (score 1):

[image]

In the Organizer, under Repositories, there's a sidebar containing all your repositories. Expand your repository if necessary. Then choose Branches and voilà! Down to the left is your "Add Branch" button.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Newbie with SVN :) Forgot to input branches path for repository, so this yellow folder wasn't visible.